# Python - order list of lists by multiple column indexes

Tags: python, sorting, multiple-columns

Let's say I've the following list x in Python

```
[['a',6,'aa']
['d',7,'bb']]
['c',1,'cc']
['a',4,'dd']
['d',2,'ee']]
```

and I want to sort its elements in order to obtain the following result

```
[['a',4,'dd']
['a',6,'aa']
['c',1,'cc']
['d',2,'ee']
['d',7,'bb']]
```

that is I want to sort it by two columns, the first one (the most important) and the second one (the less important). This is probably a duplicate question but I haven't been able to find the solution...

Comment: You can try:  'data.sort(0)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it does not matter whether you sort by the third column as well, or not, you can use plain `sort` here, and get the same result:

```
>>> sorted(a)
[['a', 4, 'dd'], ['a', 6, 'aa'], ['c', 1, 'cc'], ['d', 2, 'ee'], ['d', 7, 'bb']]
```

This is because lists are compared left to right and sorted in lexicographical order.

If you did want to order by arbitrary column order, you should use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), which is faster than using a `lambda` function for the `key`.

```
>>> import operator
>>> sorted(a, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 0))  # order by column 1 first, then 0.
[['c', 1, 'cc'], ['d', 2, 'ee'], ['a', 4, 'dd'], ['a', 6, 'aa'], ['d', 7, 'bb']]
```

Answer (score 7):

The following sorts list by the first element, then by the second element:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))
[['a', 4, 'dd'], ['a', 6, 'aa'], ['c', 1, 'cc'], ['d', 2, 'ee'], ['d', 7, 'bb']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `sorted` as `sorted` automatically handles if the sorting is applied from first element to last.

```
a = [['a',6,'aa'],['d',7,'bb'],['c',1,'cc'],['a',4,'dd'],['d',2,'ee']]
sorted(a)

[['a', 4, 'dd'],
['a', 6, 'aa'],
['c', 1, 'cc'],
['d', 2, 'ee'],
['d', 7, 'bb']]
```